# Arabic characters being displayed as question marks

Tags: php, mysql, encoding

I've inserted arabic characters into my database and as they're being displayed as question marks

I use SafeMySQL class to connect to the database and I set my charset to utf8
All my tables are set to utf8_general_ci and my database is also set to utf8_general_ci

I force a utf8 encoding in htaccess and inside the html

Does anyone have any idea what may have been left out of this that is still displaying arabic characters as question marks?

Comment: Are they displaying as question marks or were they stored as question marks?

Comment: Stored as question marks @Noah

Comment: Try inserting the data through phpmyadmin directly. You'll have to check each column of the tables

Comment: Warning: #1366 Incorrect string value: '\xD9\x85\xD8\xAB\xD8\xA7...' for column 'report_message' at row 1
@Noah

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: You may also need to set the connection to the database to utf8.

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of SafeMysql. By default [this library is using `utf8` encoding](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql/blob/master/safemysql.class.php#L85), so there should be no problem with database connection encoding, unless you are explicitly setting some other encoding.

From the error message you gave in comments,

> Warning: #1366 Incorrect string value: '\xD9\x85\xD8\xAB\xD8\xA7...' for column 'report_message' at row 1

I would say that you have to double-check your table's (and fields) charset.

Run the following query and see, if the table's definition indeed contain utf8 in all respective places:

```
DESCRIBE TABLE table_name
```